# Integertype() in schema StructType

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, struct, schema, pyspark

I am trying to define a schema to convert a blank list into dataframe as per syntax below:

```
data=[]

schema = StructType([
StructField("Table_Flag",StringType(),True),
StructField("TableID",IntegerType(),False),
StructField("Entry_No",StringType(),True),
StructField("Dimension_Code",StringType(),True),
StructField("Dimension_Value_Code",StringType(),True)
])

data=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
```

but it is giving a error of name 'IntegerType' is not defined.
I have tried with BooleanType, DecimalType, FloatType,IntegralType but none is working. Only StringType and DataType is available as datatypes.
As per documentation types.py IntegerType is defined in examples.

Please suggest. I am working on spark version 2.0.1

Comment: Have you imported the types? `from pyspark.sql.types import *`

Comment: Thanks Daniel.. I had just imported StructType,StructField.

Answer (score 16):

Add import at the beginning of the file:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
```

Or even simpler:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

To import all classes from `pyspark.sql.types`